# How come the edit post page takes so long to load?

Tags: performance, wordpress

I just setup a new Wordpress blog at home, and no other pages takes forever...I am trying to just add an image to the post, but it is just  taking forever...none of the other pages takes so long to load...

And i have just optimized all my tables via mysq and a scheduled task, so i don't see why it's taking so long to load...

Comment: By "at home", I presume you mean on your personal workstation in your house?

What kind of optimizations have you done? I don't ever see major issues with wordpress running on my VPS (two CPU, 768M RAM, CentOS 4), even with heavy system load.

What platform did you install-to? Linux, Windows, *BSD?

Comment: Personal PC Win XP Pro 4 gigs ram, 2 500 gig hd's,

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing EXACTLY the same issue...

here is what I did to boost the performance by 5x

I added my Google Analytics code into the GA plugin

I would guess that if you have implemented GA... you could also disable it too!

since GA displays on the edit posts page, it was slowing down my page display
taking up to 20 secs to load!

now the entire page loads in under 4 secs